# Multicolumn table format problem

Tags: tables, formatting, matrices

I have been reading some very nice answers on this site on how to construct tables. I am showing below what I have written.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{}  
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{$n$} \\ \cline{3-8}
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} 
    & $0$ & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ \\ \cline{2-8}
    \multirow{4}{*}{$\ell$} 
    & $0$ & a & b & c & d \\ \cline{2-8}    
    & $1$ & a & b & c & d \\ \cline{2-8}
    & $2$ & a & b & c & d \\ \cline{2-8}
    & $3$ & a & b & c & d \\ \cline{2-8}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{test table.}
  \label{tab: test}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which results in [image: table]

I do not understand what and why things are going wrong in the final column and is not presented like the others. Any help would be appreciated. Also, I would appreciate a minimal example to generalise this to a bigger matrix if that's not too much trouble.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You define a total of 9 columns, but as far as I can tell, you will only need 6 for you table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following example, I have removed superfluous column specifiers (you had a total of 9 but your table only needs 6 of them). I have accordingly adapted the `\cline` commands to fit the respective column numbers and replaced `\multicolumn{4}{c}{}` with `\multicolumn{2}{c}{}`.  I have also removed unnecessary math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{}     & \multicolumn{4}{c}{$n$} \\ \cline{3-6}
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}        & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3       \\ \cline{2-6}
    \multirow{4}{*}{$\ell$}  & 0 & a & b & c & d       \\ \cline{2-6}  
                             & 1 & a & b & c & d       \\ \cline{2-6}
                             & 2 & a & b & c & d       \\ \cline{2-6}
                             & 3 & a & b & c & d       \\ \cline{2-6}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{test table.}
  \label{tab: test}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to adapt this solution to a bigger table, you will have to add the correnponding amount of column specifiers, modify the `\multicolumn{4}{c}{$n$}` and `\multirow{4}{*}{$\ell$}` commands to correctly center the respective headers and also adapt the `\cline` commands according to your new maximum number of columns.

Here is the correnponding code for a larger table, in which a did the above mentioned changes:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{}     & \multicolumn{6}{c}{$n$}    \\ \cline{3-8}
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}        & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\ \cline{2-8}
    \multirow{6}{*}{$\ell$}  & 0 & a & b & c & d & e & f  \\ \cline{2-8}  
                             & 1 & a & b & c & d & e & f  \\ \cline{2-8}
                             & 2 & a & b & c & d & e & f  \\ \cline{2-8}
                             & 3 & a & b & c & d & e & f  \\ \cline{2-8}
                             & 4 & a & b & c & d & e & f  \\ \cline{2-8}
                             & 5 & a & b & c & d & e & f  \\ \cline{2-8}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{test table.}
  \label{tab: test}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @A_user_with_NoName: You're welcome. I have also added a short explanation about the necessary changes if you want to get this kind of table with more columns and rows. I have also included a small example on that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that table easily with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[first-col,first-row,hvlines,corners=NW]
                    &   & \Block{1-4}{$n$} \\ 
                    &   & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3    \\ 
\Block{4-1}{$\ell$} & 0 & a & b & c & d    \\ 
                    & 1 & a & b & c & d    \\ 
                    & 2 & a & b & c & d    \\ 
                    & 3 & a & b & c & d    \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{test table.}
\label{tab: test}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]